# Pandas rank specify order

Tags: pandas, aggregate, rank

I'd like to specify rank order in pandas. I know you can do it when you do:

```
df.groupby([x, y]).rank(ascending=False)
```

**Question 1**

How can I specify the ranking order (ascending=False) inside agg method:

```
df.groupby([x, y]).agg({
        ('r', 'c'): 'rank'
    })
```

**Question 2**

```
df.groupby([x, y])['r', 'c'].rank(ascending=False)
```

Throws an error: `KeyError: Columns not found`

How can I specify a multi lelvel columns for rank?

Data Structure is as follows:

```
                                            r 
                                            c 
z         x                           y                             
1         2016-11-01 00:00:00+00:00   3121  143       
                                      3923  11      
                                      3953  4    
                                      4880  12
```

Comment: regarding question 2 it should be `df.groupby([x, y])[['r', 'c']].rank(ascending=False)` this is because it's syntatic sugar for `df['r', 'c'].groupby([x, y]).rank(ascending=False)` which won't work

Comment: @EdChum - for me it works perfect

Comment: @jezrael this used to fail previously raising a `KeyError`, it looks like they fixed this at some point

Comment: @EdChum i still get `KeyError: Columns not found` by adding the second squared brackets. What I failed to mention is that the df in my example is already a groupby.agg outcome (not sure if thats important). To be clear, I am able to do df['r', 'c'] (before grouping the second time) without a `KeyError`

Comment: Guys, please add pandas version numbers, instead of "at some point" and "it works now". pandas 0.19.1 was Nov 3, 2016.

Comment: @tadalendas: if your df was actually a grouped_df, then `ungroup()` it before doing further stuff. Please post reproducible code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use:

```
x = 'x'
y = 'y'
b = df[('r','c')].groupby(level=[x, y]).rank(ascending=False)
print (b)
z  x                          y   
1  2016-11-01 00:00:00+00:00  3121    1.0
                              3923    1.0
                              3953    1.0
                              4880    1.0
Name: (r, c), dtype: float64
```

Or need `tuple` - add `,` to the end:

```
x = 'x'
y = 'y'
b = df.groupby(level=[x, y])[('r','c'), ].rank(ascending=False)
print (b)
                                    r
                                    c
z x                         y        
1 2016-11-01 00:00:00+00:00 3121  1.0
                            3923  1.0
                            3953  1.0
                            4880  1.0
#print (df)
```

Comment: 'r' and 'c' is the same column just different levels. Apologies for not being clear enough

Comment: Can you add sample data? Maybe help my sample dataframe.

Comment: added example structure

Comment: very complicated... I have no idea how specify in `agg`

Comment: Thanks, will mark your answer as the correct one in a day. I'd like to wait and see if someone knows the answer to the 1st question.

Comment: Interesting, for me `b = df.groupby(level=[x, y]).agg({('r', 'c'): 'rank'})` works perfectly.

Comment: I use pandas `0.19.1` version.

Comment: well, how would you specify the ranking order inside the `agg` function. That is `ascending=False` ?

Comment: I think it is bug, see [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/14741). Because this can works, I hope `print (df.groupby(level=[x, y]).agg({('r', 'c'): lambda x: x.rank(ascending=False)}))`